# akka getContext(). become() HotSwap not receiving messages

Tags: akka

having code in akka and playing with become() need to understand why it receive only first msg and then it ignores ...

```
package ping_pong;
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;

public class PingPongActor extends AbstractActor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ActorSystem _system = ActorSystem.create("PingPongActorApp");
        ActorRef masterpp = _system.actorOf(Props.create(PingPongActor.class),                 "pp");

        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        System.out.println("after first msg");
        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PING, masterpp);
        System.out.println("last msg");

    }

    static String PING = "PING";
    static String PONG = "PONG";
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(String.class, ua -> {
            if (ua.matches(PING)) {
                System.out.println("PING" + count);
                count += 1;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (count <= 10) {
                    getSelf().tell(PONG, getSelf());
                }

                getContext().become(receiveBuilder().match(String.class, ua1 -> {
                    if (ua1.matches(PONG)) {
                        System.out.println("PONG" + count);
                        count += 1;
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        getContext().unbecome();
                    }
                }).build());

                if (count > 10) {
                    System.out.println("DONE" + count);
                    getContext().stop(getSelf());
                }
            }
        }
        ).build();
    }
}
```

It gives result:

> 21:36:34.098 [PingPongActorApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO
> akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started after first msg
> last msg PING0 PONG1

the question is why it ignores the other PING or also PONG messages ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `getContext().become`, you are replacing the *entire* `Receive` for that actor, so

```java
getContext().become(receiveBuilder().match(String.class, ua1 -> {
    if (ua1.matches(PONG)) {
        System.out.println("PONG" + count);
        count += 1;
        Thread.sleep(100);
        getContext().unbecome();
    }
}).build());
```

You are installing a `Receive` which will only respond to messages matching `PONG`.

As an aside: `Thread.sleep` is basically the single worst thing you can do in an actor, as it prevents the actor from doing anything and also consumes a dispatcher thread.  It would be a much better idea to schedule a message to yourself in 100 millis which would then trigger the `unbecome`.

Comment: thank you for answer,

still when I change with:

        System.out.println("after first msg");
        masterpp.tell(PONG, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PONG, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PONG, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PONG, masterpp);
        masterpp.tell(PONG, masterpp);
        System.out.println("last msg");
  

result is same, it looks like it is not receiving at all (any message) ....

Comment: I figured out myself, this sample helps me understand how messages get taken from mailbox and how processes in actor ... thanks for clearing ...